# Batch image search with Google Sheets

Tags: xml, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-search

I am using Google Sheets to generate image URLs on a list of things by using `ImportXML` function.

Example:

- Cell A1 = `Flower`
- Cell B1 `="https://www.google.com/search?q="&A1&"&source=lnms&tbm=isch"`
- Cell C1 `=transpose(importxml(B1,"//img/@src"))`

The results of Cell C1 is a list of image URLs from the google image search.
Unfortunately, these images are all thumbnails.

How can I amend the above formulae to **obtain bigger-sized images?**

Comment: I don't think that this will be possible by using IMPORXML as it can't process JavaScript nor read resource files.

Answer (score 0):

you can't. all you can get are those thumbnails of images and its because you are trying to scrape Google (which thumbnails them for your view for you) and not actual images which are behind those thumbnails. the maximum you can do is to artificially upscale them, but that's not worth it I guess, because quality-wise it will get even worse.

Comment: Instead i transpose many images with different links but receive just the first image. When i transpose text it shows all texts from different links but just one image from all links. Any idea?